# Jmeter - Accessing Regex Array Variables In Beanshell

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have problems picking up variables set by the Regular Expression
Extractor in a Beanshell.

1. I have an HTTP Request sampler which returns a list of 50 numbers in random form (4, 2, 1, 3....50, 45) which I have extracted via regEx.
2. Now I want to get each and every numbers in a variable so I used again regEx with expression (.+?)(,) on JMeter variable from step# 1 above.
3. I have problem here at this step when I am using BeanShell to access these values

Wasn't very sure I used below:

```
long var1 = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("Number_i"));
print("Value of var1: " +var1);
```

Practically I want to do this:

```
for (i=0; i<50; i++) {
  if (var1==1) {
    do this
  }
}
```

I am not adept at Jmeter, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 3):

Given you extract variables using Regular Expression Extractor and you have > 1 match you **already** have multiple variables, you can check them using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination

[image: Debug Sampler]

So you can access variables in JMeter like:

```
${number_1}
${number_2}
```

and in Beanshell test elements using `vars` shorthand which stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like:

```
vars.get("number_1");
vars.get("number_2");
```

Example code which will iterate all the matches and "do something" when current variable value is "1"

```
int matches = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("number_matchNr"));

for (int i=1; i<=matches; i++) {

    if (vars.get("number_" + i).equals("1")) {
        log.info("Variable: number_" + i + " is 1");
        // do something
    }
}
```

[image: Beanshell compare variables]

See [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/) - JavaDoc on all JMeter classes and [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information on how to get started with Beanshell in JMeter